# GWT switching between panels/views

Tags: eclipse, gwt

Here is my Entry point class

```
        public class TestUI implements EntryPoint
    {
        Panel1 panel1 = new Panel1();
        public void onModuleLoad()
        {
            final RootPanel rootPanel = RootPanel.get();

            Button btnButtonOnRoot = new Button("Go to next view");
            btnButtonOnRoot.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                    rootPanel.clear();
                    rootPanel.add( panel1 );
                }
            });
            rootPanel.add(btnButtonOnRoot, 72, 40);
        }
    }
```

Works ok but I want to use something other than a Panel as the view to load when I click the button.
In Eclipse when I click on my client package I get the option to add a Panel, A Composite among other things.  Problem is when I go to edit these with my UI designer I can only put a single widget on each one.  What I would like to do is have the ability to clear the rootpanel and add an EntryPoint type class to it as I can edit EntryPoint classes with my UI designer.  What other type of Classes can I add to a panel that would be editable in a UI designer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dont use that WYSIWYG-editors. They are nice to get you started, but building UIs in GWT really is no magic. You have a panel A and add components aa, ab and ac. Then you have another panel and so on.

And one more advice: Try not to use the rootpanel. It behaves a little different than other panels as it actually is no panel. Try to add a ContentPanel to the RootPanel and add elements to that ContentPanel. The ContentPanel then is added to the RootPanel.